# Mismatch between draft and published table if no newline above table

Tags: bug

## Problem

When formatting a table for a post, there is a mismatch between the draft preview and the published version. In the draft, if there is no newline ahead of the table, the table still looks correct. However, in the published version, it is instead displayed as unformatted inline code. The solution is to add a newline ahead of the table. I would still consider this to be a bug, as the preview does not match the final result. I have added pictures (before and after) to this post to demonstrate the bug in action.

| Sample | Table |
| --- | --- |
| Foo | Bar |

## How to reproduce

### No newline above table

#### Preview

[image: Preview, no newline above table]
*No newline ahead of table. Preview display indicates this is OK.*

#### Published

[image: Published, no newline above table]
*Please notice how the table is now inline code.*

### Newline added above table

#### Preview

[image: Preview, newline added above table]
*Newline added above table. There is no change in the preview, that is, it displays as expected a correctly formatted table.*

#### Published

[image: Published, newline added above table]

*As can be seen, the edit (adding a newline) allowed the table to be displayed correctly when published.*

Comment: Does this issue exist only on Latin Language site, or is it found on other Stack Exchange sites too?

Comment: @cnread I would be very surprised if this was specific to us, as we have no special formatting features, but it would certainly be worth verifying.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, That's what I thought, which makes me wonder whether Latin Meta is really the best place for this issue to be raised.

Comment: @cnread My understanding is that developers follow the bug tag on all metas, so it does not go unheard. On our meta we can provide more friendly answers than what is to be expected on the network-wide meta site, although now Canned Man has answered his own question about getting tables to work. It makes sense to me to ask for support and report bugs on this local meta; they can always be reposted wider if needed.